# How can I Improve the efficiency of my Json parsing code?

Tags: c#, json

I wrote some code and it works, but I double-convert json twice, and it's a little embarrassing.

I get data that is wrapped in a "d" object, how can I get its contents right away

**Here's the Json that I get:**

```
{
    "d": [
    {
        "__type": "MdoCommonWs.WsStructures.WsWmsLookupResult",
        "CallResult": {
            "Id": 0,
            "Data": null,
            "ErrorId": 0,
            "ErrorDescription": null
        },
        "Article": {
            "Id": "001",
            "Description": "ANKER M12 MECHANISCH",
            "Unit": "pieces",
            "UnitPrice": 7,
            "MinStock": 0,
            "MaxStock": 0,
            "Info": "ANKER MECHANISCH M12",
            "Photo": [],
            "PhotoUrl": "",
            "WeightUnit": "kg",
            "Weight": 0.05,
            "CountStock": 0
        },
        "Locations": [
            {
                "LocationId": "00.00.AA.01.01.01.02",
                "Type": 0,
                "IsBlocked": false,
                "ArticleId": "001",
                "Stock": 2,
                "TotalStock": 2,
                "LastActionDate": "/Date(1480334382093)/",
                "LastInventoryDate": "/Date(1480334319527)/"
            }
        ],
    }],
}
```

**Here is my code to convert:**

```
var rootJObject = JObject.Parse(stringSerialized);
var serialize = rootJObject["d"].ToString();

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(serialize);
```

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: Can't you just return rootObject["d"]? It's already deserialized.

Comment: That would return a `JObject` @PalleDue, I'm guessing OP wants it strongly typed `TResult`

Comment: How about creating an object around `d` ?

Comment: @Liam: Yes, of course. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare an object around your `d` member:

```
public class Root<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("d")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then simply:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root<TResult>>(json).Data;
```

---

Another method is to deserialize into a `JObject`:

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("d")]
    public JObject Data { get; set; }
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json).Data.ToObject<TResult>();
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, this is the best i think

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this, here's what I use:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> ParseJson<TResult>(string stringSerialized)
{
  using (StringReader streamReader = new StringReader(stringSerialized))
  using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
  {
            JObject parsedData = await JObject.LoadAsync(jsonTextReader);
            if (parsedData == null || parsedData["d"] == null || parsedData["d"].Children().Any() == false)
                return new List<T>();
            else
                return parsedData["d"].Children().Select(s => s.ToObject<TResult>());
   }
 }
```

If `stringSerialized` is coming from a Stream you can make this more efficient but just processing that stream directly, this saves you turning the stream into a string to turn the string into an object:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> ParseStream<TResult>(Stream contentStream)
    {

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(contentStream))
        using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            jsonTextReader.DateFormatString = _dateFormatString;
            JObject parsedData = await JObject.LoadAsync(jsonTextReader);
            if (parsedData == null || parsedData["d"] == null || parsedData["d"].Children().Any() == false)
                return new List<TResult>();
            else
                return parsedData["d"].Children().Select(s => s.ToObject<TResult>());
        }
    }
```

Be sure to dispose and clean up `Stream contentStream` correctly using `using`.

For a non `async` version just replace:

```
JObject parsedData = await JObject.LoadAsync(jsonTextReader);
```

with

```
JObject parsedData = JObject.Load(jsonTextReader);
```

and change the signature to:

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> ParseJson<TResult>
```